# How to sort a numbered text file in unix?

Tags: regex, sorting, ubuntu, unix, terminal

Ex: I have a text file

```
1.dog
2.cat
3.apple
4.bear
```

And I want to sort it to

```
3.apple
4.bear
2.cat
1.dog
```

I don't understand how to sort it because there is no space after the period and the first letter of the lines so I'm not able to simply say sort +1 file.txt or anything. Is there any way I can use some sort of substring to dodge the numbered list and period to sort it based on what comes afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sort -t . -k2 file
```

Check `man sort`